# How to Search data from a list of Key-Value pair that it is in list or not

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list like this :

```
a = [('X', '63.658'), ('Y', '21.066'), ('Z', '230.989'), 
     ('X', '63.424'), ('Y', '21.419'), ('Z', '231.06'), 
     ('X', '63.219'), ('Y', '21.805'), ('Z', '231.132'), 
     ('X', '63.051'), ('Y', '22.206'), ('Z', '231.202'), 
     ('X', '62.915'), ('Y', '22.63'), ('Z', '231.272'), 
     ('X', '62.811'), ('Y', '23.073'), ('Z', '231.341')]
```

From this list, I wrote code for max and min values of `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

However, I also want to print that **If I remove the pairs of X then X will not be in the list and it should print that "X is Empty". same if there are pairs for A-Z in which A,B,G,S,X and so on are not in list then this should print like "A is Empty.. B is Empty.. G is Empty..S is Empty..X is Empty.."Also should print the min and max values of remaining those are in list..**

This is my code in python :

```
 with open(r'/path of file...txt') as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
        lines=''.join(lines)
        lines=lines.split()
        a=[]
        for i in lines:
            match=re.match(r"([a-z]+)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)",i,re.I)
            if match:
                a.append(match.groups())
    print a
    for tuples in a:
        key, value = tuples[0], float(tuples[1])
        groups[key].append(value)

    for key, values in groups.iteritems():
        print key, max(values), min(values)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: No problm with my current code...its working fine..but I'm not getting any idea that how to and where to put condition that I mentioned in question..!!

Comment: The section of your question in bold makes no sense to me: remove what pairs? What are `A`, `B`, `G`, etc.; other lists of tuples?

Comment: ('X', '63.658'), ('X', '63.424'), ('X', '62.811')
These pairs if I remove all then it should print min and max of Y and Z as well as print "X is Empty" also...

Comment: On what basis are they "pairs"? When and why would you remove them? Should the code report missing values for every uppercase letter not in the list?

Comment: mention your exact problem

Comment: These are key-value pairs..I have some files that contains these type of key-value pairs and for different letters like this is for X,Y and Z. same as another file it is for A,B,C...K and so on..so i need one program that can find min and max values and those letters that are not in list/file should print "A is empty or B..or other"..

Comment: @user3522951 Take a look at my answer, is that the kind of process that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary to hold the values for each character:

```
a = [('X', '63.658'), ('Y', '21.066'), ...]

processed = {}

for char, value in data:
    if char not in processed:
        processed[char] = []
    processed[char].append(value)
```

Then iterate through all ASCII uppercase characters, printing either the calculated values or e.g. `"N is empty..."`

```
import string

for char in string.ascii_uppercase:
    if char not in processed:
        print("{0} is empty...".format(char))
    else:
        print("{0}: min={1}, max={2}".format(char, 
                                             min(processed[char]),
                                             max(processed[char])))
```

You could simplify slightly with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

processed = defaultdict(list)

for char, value in data:
    processed[char].append(value)
```

Generally, I would suggest breaking up your program a bit - separate the import of tuple data from a text file into one function, and processing the list into another. This makes it easier to develop and test each in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

elems = set(c for c, n in a)
for c in ascii_uppercase:  # Or whatever string of characters you want to check.
    if c in elems:
        relevant = [t for t in a if t[0] == c]
        print((c, max(relevant)[1], min(relevant)[1]))
    else:
        print((c, None))
```

That should work very nicely. The code above is not formatted to have a pretty output, but that is just a matter of you playing with the `print` functions a little.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) to hold the values you've read it may be easier

```
from collections import defaultdict
items = defaultdict(list)

groups = match.groups()
items[groups[0]].append(float(groups[1]))
```

then you'll end up with only a single key in the dictionary for each element and you can delete any element values simply by using

```
del items['X']
```

and you can use

```
if 'X' not in items:
    print('X is empty')
else:
    values = items['X']
    avg = sum(values) / len(values)
    min = min(values)
    max = max(values)
```

Comment: what if I've multiple chars like A,B,C,D,X,Y,Z or say for all chars..??

Comment: then wrap the `if` in a `for` loop

    `import string; for ch in string.ascii_letters:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use set with filter:

```
k=set([i[0] for i in a])
for ki in k:
    l=filter(lambda x:x[0]==ki, a)
    print "max:", max(l), "min: ", min(l)
```

Output:

```
max: ('Y', '23.073') min:  ('Y', '21.066')
max: ('X', '63.658') min:  ('X', '62.811')
max: ('Z', '231.341') min:  ('Z', '230.989')
```

1. First get unique keys from dataset
2. Form list from keys
3. pass the list to max function